# Comparing cells from two crosstabs / chi-squared goodness of fit test?

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, frequency

I have two crosstabs that I'd like to compare for each cell for significance. Both crosstabs have the same variables and the same amount of total observations, but the frequency distribution is different across cells.
This is a before/after manipulation task, so the same participants did the task twice. **I need to see whether the manipulation caused any significant changes in the frequency distribution across cells.**
I compared the two crosstabs based on the standard residuals to see which cell has the strongest association, and compared whether the strongest cells are the same, but did this without any statistical test. **So which test can I use in order to conclude that the manipulation made a difference (or not) in frequency distribution for each cell?**

Also, I tried using the **goodness of fit test**, task1 as expected and task2 as observed counts. My logic was that if the analysis is significant, it means the two distributions are different and I can see which ones are by looking at the residuals. I see that SPSS computes unstandardized residuals, but do you think if I compute them myself this would be a good way to achieve my goal or would I need another test that can perhaps compare two crosstabs?